# Error when reading a file in Spark

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark, datastax-enterprise

I'm having a hard time figuring out why Spark is not accessing a file that I add to the context. Below is my code in the repl:

```
scala> sc.addFile("/home/ubuntu/my_demo/src/main/resources/feature_matrix.json")

scala> val featureFile = sc.textFile(SparkFiles.get("feature_matrix.json"))

featureFile: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = /tmp/spark/ubuntu/spark-d7a13d92-2923-4a04-a9a5-ad93b3650167/feature_matrix.json MappedRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:60

scala> featureFile.first()
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: cfs://172.30.26.95/tmp/spark/ubuntu/spark-d7a13d92-2923-4a04-a9a5-ad93b3650167/feature_matrix.json
```

The file does in fact exist at  `/tmp/spark/ubuntu/spark-d7a13d92-2923-4a04-a9a5-ad93b3650167/feature_matrix.json`

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is your cluster local or remote?

Comment: I am also facing same type of problem.

Comment: This cluster is remote.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `addFile`, then you need to use `get` to retrieve it. Also, the `addFile` method is lazy, so it is very possible that it was not put in the location you are finding it until you actually call `first`, so you are creating this kind of circle.

All that being said, I don't know that using `SparkFiles` as the first action is ever going to be a smart idea. Use something like `--files` with `SparkSubmit` and the files will be put in your working directory.